# Next.js route.replace changing custom html lang attribute set in _document.js to current local

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, internationalization

I am using Next js with i18n-routing with following next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr', 'nl'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
}
```

To set custom html lang attribute. I am overriding html lang attribute to en-IN using _document.js

```
    export default function Document() {
      return (
        <Html lang="en-IN"> // overriding it to en-IN
          <Head />
          <body>
            <Main />
            <NextScript />
          </body>
        </Html>
      )
    }
```

But when I try to add query params to the url using router.replace(). It changes the html lang attribute to current local i.e. "en".

```
export default function IndexPage(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const addQueryParam = () => {
    router.replace(
      { query: { foo: 'bar' } },
      { query: { foo: 'bar' } },
      { shallow: true }
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Index page &nbsp;</h1>
      <button onClick={addQueryParam}>Add Query Param</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[StackBlitz Code Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-myjnkx-awv7kt?file=pages/index.js): In this sample code when i click on button, it adds query param to url and also changes the html lang attribute to en.

I came to know through Next.js [i18n-routing documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#search-engine-optimization) that it does it for SEO.

So how can I prevent Next.js from changing html lang attribute?

Comment: Why are you setting a different locale in your `lang` attribute compared to the ones defined in the config? Why not just use `en-IN` in the `locales` array in the i18n config?

Comment: @juliomalves the reason is our local routes are different than lang attribute required third party plugin in page. For example, local url is `xyz.com/in` but lang attribute required by third party plugin should be `en-IN`. The third party plugin doesn't work properly with `in`  lang attribute